# Unable to install uberwriter

Tags: apt, logo

I am unable to install [Uberwriter](http://uberwriter.wolfvollprecht.de/) on Loki. I get the following when trying to run `apt-get update` after adding the uberwriter repo with `sudo add-apt-repository`:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/w-vollprecht/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/w-vollprecht/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Is there a way to override this? Another question here suggested commenting out the cdrom entry in `sources.list` but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

UberWriter does not support Ubuntu 16.04 (upon which elementary is based), thus the command to add the PPA fails.

You may however install it from source with the following:

1. Install pre-requisite packages: `sudo apt install build-essential`
2. Grab the code: `bzr branch lp:uberwriter`
3. From inside the project directory, install UberWriter with `sudo python setup.py install`.